# React white screen of death, why does commenting out this code fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a simple react app to take trivia questions and answers from an api and display them as a game.

My development of this app has been running smoothly and updating as per expected, however when I imported a decode function to make the trivia questions present correctly, I noticed that further edits of the code would result in a blank white screen, after commenting out some code I've managed to isolate what code seems to be causing the issue.

App.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import Questions from './Questions'
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'
import { decode } from 'he'

function App() {
  const [tempState, setTempState] = React.useState(false)
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({})

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=9&difficulty=medium")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(info => setData(info.results.map(item => {
        return { 
          type: item.type, 
          question: item.question, 
          correct_answer: item.correct_answer, 
          incorrect_answers: item.incorrect_answers,
          id: nanoid() 
        }})))
  }, [])

  const questionElements = data.map(item => (
    <Questions 
      key={item.id}
      type={item.type}
      question={item.question}
      correct_answer={item.correct_answer}
      incorrect_answers={item.incorrect_answers}
    />
  ))
  
  return (
    <main>
      <img className="blob--top"
        src={require('./blobs.png')}
      />

      <img className="blob--bottom"
        src={require('./blobs1.png')}
      />

      {tempState ?
        <div className="quiz--container">
          <div>
             {questionElements}
          </div>
        </div> :
        <>
          <div className="title--container">
            <div className="title--init">
              <h2 className="title--header">Quizzical</h2>
              <h4 className="title--subheader">A battle of the brains</h4>
              <button className="game--start"
                onClick={() => setTempState(!tempState)}
              >
                Start quiz</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      }
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Questions.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { decode } from 'he'

export default function Questions(props) {
    return(
        <div className="question--container">
            <h4>{decode(props.question)}</h4>
            <div className="question--items">
                <button>{decode(props.correct_answer)}</button>
                <button>{decode(props.incorrect_answers[0])}</button>
                <button>{decode(props.incorrect_answers[1])}</button>
                <button>{decode(props.incorrect_answers[2])}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

commenting out the following two code sections in App.js resolves the error

```js
const questionElements = data.map(item => (
   <Questions 
      key={item.id}
      type={item.type}
      question={item.question}
      correct_answer={item.correct_answer}
      incorrect_answers={item.incorrect_answers}
   />
))
```

```html
<div>
   {questionElements}
</div>
```

any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? no error messages show up in react, it just shows a blank white screen.

Comment: Can u share a sandbox link? @jacksonmendoza

Comment: Blank screen is displayed when an unexpected error happens and React cant continue rendering. Check the console to check the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blank white screen is caused by the error `data.map is not a function`, which is caused by your setting default value of the `data` state to be an empty object while it should be an empty array (so that you can map through).

To fix this error, simply set the default value of `data` to be an empty array.

```js
const [data, setData] = React.useState([])
```

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/inspiring-rhodes-gp5kki?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Jesus, why is this a thing? The 'React way' I guess :shrug: